# Can not find default endpoint in MVVM project

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, mvvm

I have a solution with an MVVM project which references a WCF web service project, and a WPF project which is the GUI part.

When I add in the WPF window XAML a reference to the MVVM main class, I have an error : can not find dafault endpoint which references the contract "MarketService.IService1" in the configuration section of the client ServiceModel.This can be due to the configuration file which is not found, or that the endpoint which correspond to that endpoint is not found in the client element.

The error arises in the MVVM project, when the web service is called:

```
public class MainWindowMVVM
{
    private IList<Magasin> _Magasins = new ObservableCollection<Magasin>();
    public IList<Magasin> Magasins {
        set
        {
            _Magasins = value;
        }

        get
        {
            return _Magasins;
        }
    }

    public MainWindowMVVM()
    {

        //au démarrage, magasins est remplie grâce à un appel au service
        using (var market = new MarketService.Service1Client())    <---- here is the error
        {
            Supermarche retour = market.GetSupermarche();
            //copier retour.magasins dans magasins
            foreach (Magasin mg in retour.Magasins)
            {
                Magasins.Add(mg);


            }

        }

        //trvMarket.ItemsSource = Magasins;

    }
}
```

Here is how the MVVM class is included in the WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="UserInterface.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserInterface"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Market Client" Height="450" Width="800"
    xmlns:self="clr-namespace:Model;assembly=Model"
    xmlns:mvvmPart="clr-namespace:MVVM;assembly=MVVM"   <-- here I include the project

    >

<Window.Resources>
    <local:NotConverter x:Key="NotConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle_ExpandAll" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <mvvmPart:MainWindowMVVM/>  <--here I want to make a default access to the MVVM class
...
```

In the last arrow, visual studio shows the same error as above(concerning the default endpoint).

To add the web service to the MVVM project, I use the visual studio wizard:
[image: wizard]

Please note that the WPF project does not include any reference to the web service : I did not find it necessary.

Here is the configuration file app.config in the MVVM project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/market11/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="MarketService.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Do you know what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the configuration to the `App.config` file of the running exectable, i.e. the one in the WPF application project.

The `App.config` file in a referenced class library project is not used.

You may also create the binding programmatically:

```
var binding = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/market11/Service1.svc");

var factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(binding, endpoint);

var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
var retour = channel.GetSupermarche();
```

Comment: I added the <system.serviceModel> tag and its children to WPF's app.config but I still have the error, even when I regenerate the solution. But I can run the WPF project... I don't understand anything. Do I have to add a service reference to the WPF project too?

Comment: @lolveley: Try to define the binding explicitly. See my updated answer.

Comment: The app works, without the explicit binding, but nevertheless the error is still here! It compiles, runs.Thank you.

Comment: @lolveley: "It works" *or* "the error is still there"? Which is it?

Comment: both! the xaml tag is underlined, so the error is here, but when I run the project, it works

Comment: If it runs, it runs. The XAML being underlines is a designer issue. It's not related to your original question. Try to restart Visual Studio.